# Spring can't autowire Map bean

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I've defined a map in spring as such:

```
<util:map id="AdditionalParams" scope="prototype" map-class="java.util.HashMap" 
          key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
    
    <entry key="Start" value="12345" />
    <entry key="Finish" value="12365" />
</util:map>
```

And then I'm autowiring this bean to a property defined as:

```
private @Autowired @Qualifier(value = "AdditionalParams") Map<String, String> additionalParams;
```

When doing this, the an exception get's thrown saying that:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DutyCreator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map DutyCreator.additionalParams; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=AdditionalParams)}
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=AdditionalParams)}

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Please share your application Context file.

Comment: You may also use the `<util:map>` xml configuration

Answer (score 121):

Starting with Spring 4.3, `@Autowired` [can inject lists and maps](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) and the given code in the question would work:

> That said, as of 4.3, collection/map and array types can be matched through Spring’s `@Autowired` type matching algorithm as well, as long as the element type information is preserved in `@Bean` return type signatures or collection inheritance hierarchies.

But with a lower Spring version, you can't autowire a collection like that. However, you can do the following:

```
@Resource(name="AdditionalParams")
private Map<String, String> additionalParams;
```

or even:

```
@Value("#{AdditionalParams}")
private Map<String, String> additionalParams;
```

Check the [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers), the tips section:

> beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot
>   be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly
>   applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans

Comment: perfect. exactly what i was looking for.. Thanks.
this worked for me.. 
@Resource(name="AdditionalParams")

Comment: Thanks, this was very unintuitive; I now know more about `map` and `util:map` than I wanted to :-/

Comment: Wow, I already spent hours on this problem. Why Spring just use autowire instead of Resource? This way just make Spring so annoying to use.

Comment: For those to whom this still won't help, don't forget to remove @Qualifier(name="AdditionalParams") or else it won't work.

Comment: Even as of Spring 5.1, `@Autowired` for a Map keyed by String does not seem to work, only working for me using `@Resource`

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your **@Qualifier(value = "AdditionalParams")** is not working.

Try using the map by following annotation :

```
@Resource
private Properties AdditionalParams;
```

and keeping your applicationContext.xml file intact.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext ctx;
private  <T> T getBean(String qualifier, Class<T> returnType){
    //use this for loop to print all bean from ctx. so you wont miss the typo.
    /*for(String s:ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames())
        log.info(s);*/
    return ctx.getBean(qualifier, returnType);
}
```

// inside your call

```
 if(providerList == null){
       providerList = ctx.getBean("providerList", Map.class);
 }
```

This Solution works good to me