# Error injecting a map using spring/JSR-330

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jsr330

I have 2 maven projects, a web-app, and a 'service' project. I am using spring to wire everything together.  I would like to create a map in my application-context.xml, and have that injected into my class. When I try to start my web application I get an error message.

Here is my class:

```
 @Named("tranformer")
 public class IdentifierTransformerImpl implements IdentifierTransformer {


private Map<String, String> identifierMap;

@Inject
public IdentifierTransformerImpl(
        @Named("identifierMap")
        final Map<String, String> identifierMap) {
            this.identifierMap= identifierMap;
}
```

and the application-context.xml:

```
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"

  <util:map id="identifierMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="Apple" value="fruit"/>
    <entry key="BlackBerry" value="fruit"/>
    <entry key="Android" value="robot"/>
   <util:map>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

I get the following error:

```
 ..... No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Named(value=identifierMap)
```

This works when I define a string in my application-context, and constructor inject it into a class, how can I do the same for a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Map collection is not supported by @Inject or @Autowired annotation (see: [Spring can't autowire Map bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913752/spring-cant-autowire-map-bean)). However I managed to autowire a Map by annotating it as a resource as suggested by that answer. Try this:

```
@Resource(name="identifierMap") private Map<String, String> identifierMap;
```

The downside is ofcourse that isn't a constructor autowiring, but a field. I haven't found a way of doing it through constructor autowiring yet

Comment: Thanks for the info. I create a 'wrapper' bean for the map and injected the map into it via application-context.xml (with getter/setter and the <property /> tag.  I could then use my @Inject annotation for putting that new bean into my identifierTransformer class.  It works, but it isn't pretty

Answer (score 0):

If that is a direct copy/paste of your xml file, you aren't ending your `<util:map>` tag. You're missing a `/` in the second one.

Comment: Yah, that was sloppy copying from my application-context. It wouldn't have caused the problems described above

Answer (score -1):

With constructor injection.

```
@Inject
public IdentifierTransformerImpl(
    @Value(value = "#{identifierMap}")
    final Map<String, String> identifierMap) {
        this.identifierMap= identifierMap;
}
```

Not ideal but Spring declines to provide a better option.

Check out more details at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8519