# Can spring @Autowired Map?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Here's the Map

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;
```

and `ISendableConverter`

```
public interface ISendableConverter {

    ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage);

    String getType();
}
```

There are some classes that implements `ISendableConverter`

I want to inject them into the variable `converters` by using spring `@Autowried` annotation.

The instance of class as value, and the result of method `getType()` as key.

like this one

```
@Component
public class SendableVoiceMsgConverter implements ISendableConverter {

    @Override
    public ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "VOICE";
    }
}
```

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: Have you actually just tried this?  It should work in Spring 2.5 and beyond.  The key will be the bean name.

Comment: No, you can't inject them into a Map where the key is the return value of a method call on a bean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring can't autowire Map bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913752/spring-cant-autowire-map-bean)

Answer (score 30):

You can create an automatically initialized map with keys of your choice using Spring Java configuration:

In class annotated with `@Configuration` annotation:

```
@Autowired
private List<ISendableConverter> sendableConverters;

@Bean
public Map<String, ISendableConverter> sendableConvertersMap() {
    Map<String, ISendableConverter> sendableConvertersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (ISendableConverter converter : sendableConverters) {
        sendableConvertersMap.put(converter.getType(), converter);
    }
    return sendableConvertersMap;
}
```

Than you inject this map with:

```
@Resource()
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> sendableConverters;
```

You can optionally add some selector string to your `@Resource` annotation if you have defined more maps of the same type.

This way all you have to do is implement `ISendableConverter` by your spring bean and it will automatically appear in Map defined above.
You don't need to create map items by hand for each implementation.

Answer (score 29):

Try with something like [@Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) - I have not tested this code.

```
@Resource(name="converters")
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;
```

or

```
@Value("#{converters}")
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;
```

From [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> > (..) beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use [@Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

This should work, only if you prepare `converters` bean like this:

```
<util:map id="converters" scope="prototype" map-class="java.util.HashMap" 
          key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="...ISendableConverter">
    <entry key="VOICE" value="sendableVoiceMsgConverter" />
</util:map>
```

This is also similar question:

- [Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)
- [Spring can't autowire Map bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913752/spring-cant-autowire-map-bean)

Comment: But this is not an attempt to inject a map that's registered as a bean.  Autowired does support injecting all implementations which is what the question asked.  See the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Comment: I have a situation. I dont want to do this from xml beans. I want to do this by annotations. Again, I cant do any hardcoding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Autwire them as lists and then loop through that list to create a map. If you could define the logic as a @Bean method, then you can get away with returning the map as a bean.

Answer (score 16):

you can do something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private List<OneTypeImageLoader> imageLoaders;
private Map<String, OneTypeImageLoader> imageLoaderMap=new HashMap<>();

@Autowired
public void setImageLoaders(List<OneTypeImageLoader> imageLoaders) {
    this.imageLoaders = imageLoaders;
    imageLoaders.forEach(l-> {
        imageLoaderMap.put(l.getType(), l);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try something like this, it works for me

```
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;

@Autowired
public void setUploadServices(Set<ISendableConverter> converters){
    this.conveters = converters.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ISendableConverter::getType, Function.identity()));
}
```

The same result can be achieved using constructor injection:

```
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;

@Autowired
public Foo(Set<ISendableConverter> converters) {
    this.conveters = converters.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ISendableConverter::getType, Function.identity()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Component("VOICE")
public class SendableVoiceMsgConverter implements ISendableConverter {

    @Override
    public ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

You may want to just add the type name directly into the component annotation, that will do the job.

Comment: What problems can this cause?

Answer (score 4):

First, set Bean name like the return value of `getType()`

```
@Component("VOICE")
public class SendableVoiceMsgConverter implements ISendableConverter {

    @Override
    public ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converters;
```

this map's V type is instance of Bean , and K type is Bean's name

Comment: Is there a Spring documentation that explains this solution? I am looking for answers on how this solution is working?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with `spring-componentmap` (https://github.com/krud-dev/spring-componentmap)

Based on your example:

```java
public interface ISendableConverter {

    ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage);

    @ComponentMapKey
    String getType();
}

@Component
public class SendableVoiceMsgConverter implements ISendableConverter {

    @Override
    public ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "VOICE";
    }
}

// Call the converter by type
@Component
class SendableMsgConverter {

    // @ComponentMap replaces @Autowired in this case
    @ComponentMap
    private Map<String, ISendableConverter> converterMap;

    public ISendableMsg convert(BaseMessage baseMessage) {
        ISendableConverter converter = converterMap.get(baseMessage.getType());
        return converter.convert(baseMessage);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I co-developed `spring-componentmap`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more generic and build something like this:

```
    public interface BasicStrategy {
        String getKey();
    }

    public final class StrategyMap<K extends BasicStrategy> extends HashMap<String, K> {

    public StrategyMap(List<K> strategies) {
        super(strategies.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(K::getKey, Function.identity())));
    }

    @Override
    public K get(Object key) {
        BasicStrategy basicStrategy = super.get(key);
        if (basicStrategy == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No strategy found for key: '" + key + "'");
        }
        return (K) basicStrategy;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this `StrategyMap` everywhere around your code like this:

```
private StrategyMap<ISendableConverter> converters;

@Autowired
public Foo(List<ISendableConverter> converters) {
    this.conveters = new StrategyMap<>(converters);
}
```

This approach generify the creation of a `StrategyMap` and also logic for the case where value is not found can be centralized.

PS: Of course `ISendableConverter` has to extend `BasicStrategy` interface.