# Spring: Map could not Autowire issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Component
public class BankServicesImpl implements BankServices {
    @Autowired
    private DataRepoImpl db;
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Component
public class DataRepoImpl implements DataRepo{
    private Map<Integer, Account> repo = new HashMap<Integer,Account>();
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Component
public class Account {
    private Integer accountID;
    private int balance;
}
```

The codes do the job, the **repo** HashMap object is created ( {} ). Yet i am trying to get the repo Map object to be generated by Spring. so i changed the DataRepoImpl into:

```
@Component
public class DataRepoImpl implements DataRepo{
    @Autowired
    private Map<Integer, Account> repo;
}

Error:
Nov 08, 2021 11:37:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, com.doubleliu.model.Account>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, com.doubleliu.model.Account>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, com.doubleliu.model.Account>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

However, when i refactor accountID and Map key into String type,
i able to produce the HashMap containing a 'dummy' variable which is weird:

```
{account=com.doubleliu.model.Account@397fbdb}
```

Back to Integer, I couldnt fix the error, I then tried to move the Autowired to the empty constructor of the DataRepoImpl class:

```
    @Autowired
    public DataRepoImpl() {
    }
```

However i get null value from **repo**, since (my assumption) the object hasnt been created or assigned to the **repo** Map variable.
Again, i then move the Autowired onto the constructor with map as the parameter:

```
    @Autowired
    public DataRepoImpl(Map<Integer, Account> repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
```

This time the **repo** object is created ( {} ) and not null, i assume that the object is created through the parameter, is this the right way to create it utilizing spring? also my IDE flag me with an error of
`Could not autowire. No beans of 'Map<Integer, Account>' type found.` but i can still compile it. i wonder how to fix it.. fyi, I am using IntelliJ IDEA

I just started learning spring for a bit, trying to completely understand before i go to the next level. so any response, solutions, comments, advice to the code, fix, and issue is very pleased especially with the autowired.
Thank you.

EDIT: i am using xml annotation based configuration

Comment: Here's what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584390/2599899

Comment: XML and Java stuff is equivalent. For this Java config you can create an equivalent XML config

Comment: Unrelated, but one important point to think about: From your example, i think the Account itself should not be a Spring bean, but rather an entity (which you usually would save in a database).

Comment: @dunni hey there, i am not really sure but Account is actually a java pojo class for oop. i also refer it to the tutorials in youtube.. am i missing something?

Comment: Program to interfaces not classes instead of `DataRepoImpl` you should inject `DataRepo`. Regarding your `Map` you need to define a bean of that type, spring will not automatically create beans for `@Autowired` fields they need to be present int he application context. But injecting a map here doesn't add much.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hey, thank you for your advice! i truly appreciate it! i just found out that i need to define the map variable itself with the key and value type in the xml. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20918905/8810061)

I just found out that i need to define the [properties](http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd) of the defined bean in the xml. everytime i define something like HashMap, add following to the xml and it enables me to inject the just defined Map bean by defining @Resource on the Map variable inside the class.

```
<util:map id="repo" scope="prototype" map-class="java.util.HashMap"
                  key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.doubleliu.model.Account"/>
```

Thank you for the help and comments, any more comments and advices are welcomed.